# How can I pass in a number when I link to a different page in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render(

    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component = { Home } />
            <Route exact path="/gallery" component = { Gallery } />
            <Route exact path="/details" component = { Details } />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,

    // Define your router and replace <Home /> with it!
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is my routing for my web app

```
        return data.map((eachData, index) => {
            return (  <Link to={{ pathname: '/details/' + this.state.selectedKey }}><PokemonInfo poke={ eachData } key={ index } /></Link> );
        });
    };
```

And this is the part of code that I try to Link to the /details page when I move to another link. I would like to pass in a number (not a state. unlike my sample code).

Briefly, I want to pass in, let's say 2, into the link, and make it direct to /details/2, and retrieve that '2' in the details.jsx component.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Details

class Details extends React.Component {

```
constructor() {
    super();


    this.state = {


        pokemon: []

    };


};

componentWillMount() {
// Called first time the comp is loaded right before the comp is added to the page
    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')
    console.log("passed" , this.props.match.params.id)
    var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + this.props.match.params.id; 

    axios.get(url)

    .then((response) => {
        // setState re-renders component
        this.setState({
            pokemon: response.data
        })

        console.log(this.state.pokemon)

    })

        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
    })
}

render() {

    return (
            <Card className = "PokemonView">
                <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header className = "PokemonView_header">
                        { this.state.pokemon.name }
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Card.Meta>
                        Pokedex #{ this.state.pokemon.id }
                    </Card.Meta>
                    <Card.Meta>
                        Height { this.state.pokemon.height }
                    </Card.Meta>
                    <Card.Meta>
                        Weight { this.state.pokemon.weight }
                    </Card.Meta>

                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
    );
}
```

}

export default Details

Comment: You should remove `exact` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component={(props) => (<Details {...props}/>) } />
```

Comment: sorry i don't get the {(props) => <Details {...props}/> part. Do you mean "<Route path="/details:id" component = { (props) => Details } />"

Comment: <Route path="/details:id" component={(props) => <Details {...props}/> this gives me a syntax error.

Comment: I am sorry can give me the exact syntax?

Comment: It worked! You rock man. But how does that ... thing even work? Can it be replaced by something else?

Comment: what has actually happened is we have created an intermediate [pure component](https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-11/) that accepts `props` from `Route` and renders the `<Details>` element with that `props` as its props ( that's what happens when we use `{...props}`. In effect it is equivalent to  
`React.createElement(Details, Object.assign({}, this.props));` )

Comment: Is there a way to directly access /details/idnumber and make the page render based on the idnumber?

Comment: it only works when I Link To the page, but not when I directly type the address to it.

Comment: It's some issue with your code. It should work. What error do you get when trying to access `this.props.match.params.id` ? Try console logging `props` as well as changing where you are calling it.

Comment: It prints the right value. It's just that I cannot directly by typing the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156585/discussion-between-dane-and-user6792790).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you set up the route like:

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component = { Details } />
```

And then in the `Details` component you get `this.props.match.params.id` to use.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do we have to change to Link To part to pass in an id?

Comment: this `Link` looks ok.  the url should be parsed based on the pattern `/details/:id`.

Comment: <Link to={{ pathname: '/details/' + '1'  }}> and console.log("passed" , this.props.match.params.id) in the 'details' page does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the route: `<Route path="/details/:myParam" component={Details} />` and can retrieve the route param with `this.props.match.params.myParam` in your Details component.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do we have to change to Link To part to pass in an id?

Comment: <Link to={'/details/' + this.state.selectedKey}> ...  should be enough

Comment: <Link to={{ pathname: '/details/' + '1'  }}> and console.log("passed" , this.props.match.params.id) in the 'details' page does not work. I used :id instead of :myParam

Comment: You also have to remove the exact from <Route exact path="/details" component = { Details } /> . Did you do that?

Comment: Does it call componentWillMount just with id as 'undefined' or does it not render the component at all?

Comment: it does not call the componentWIllMount at all

Comment: Does 'localhost.../details/1'  actually appear in your adress bar when you click the link, or is there any console output complaining?

Comment: It does appear, but the page is just blank.