# In React, how do we make the page render based on the id of the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is an extended question from 
[How can I pass in a number when I link to a different page in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685670/how-can-i-pass-in-a-number-when-i-link-to-a-different-page-in-react-js/46686229?noredirect=1#comment80323941_46686229)

I solved the issue here which was passing in a value as a prop to the page that the current page is linked to.

It does direct to the page with the correct id, and renders it correctly. But when I try to move on to the next page (page with the next id e.g. from /details/2 -> /details/3) by doing

```
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/details/' + (parseInt(this.props.match.params.id) - 1) }}><span>Prev</span></Link>

        <Link to={{ pathname: '/details/' + (parseInt(this.props.match.params.id) + 1) }}><span>Next</span></Link>
```

The link shows the right id, but it does not renders again.

Eventually, I want it to make accessible just by the id, like /details/idnum

and make it render based on the idnum.

Comment: Where's the rest of the component?

Comment: Add the prop `key={this.props.match.params.id}` to your main component that holds the one that is being switched out by the id. Please note, keys usually are the go-to for triggering a rerender when the DOM doesn't immediately recognize a change